# Cut multiline string with RegEx and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I have example text:

```
var text = `class Eee {
   test(){
     console.log("123");
   }
}
use(123, Eee);

class Ttt {
   test(){
     console.log("123");
   }
}
use(456, Ttt);


class Ooo {
   test(){
     console.log("123");
   }
}
use(111, Ooo);
`;
```

And I wont get part text for example:

```
`class Ttt {
   test(){
     console.log("123");
   }
}
use(456, Ttt);`
```

If I use RegEx:

```
let result = text.match(/^class Ttt \{(.*)/gm);
```

I have result: `[ 'class ttt {' ]`

If I use RegEx:

```
let result = text.match(/^class Ttt \{(.*)\}/gm);
```

or

```
let result = text.match(/^class Ttt \{(.*)use\([\b].Ttt\);/gm);
```

I have result: `null`.
How can I get the entire piece of text I want, not the first line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You specified where the match should start, but you also have to specify where is should end.

If the end for example is at the start of a new line and the next line should be `use(456, Ttt);` on it's own:

```
^[^\S\n]*class Ttt {[^]*?\n\s*}\s*\n\s*use\(.*\);$
```

**Note** that `\s` can also match newlines.

The pattern in parts:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\n]*` Match optional whitespace chars without newlines
- `class Ttt {`  Match literally
- `[^]*?` Match any character including newlines, as few as possible
- `\n\s*}\s*` Match a newline and `}` between optional whitespace chars
- `\nuse\(.*\);` Match a newline and `use(...);`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q4a5pO/1)

```js
var text = `class Eee {
   test(){
     console.log("123");
   }
}
use(123, Eee);

class Ttt {
   test(){
     console.log("123");
   }
}
use(456, Ttt);


class Ooo {
   test(){
     console.log("123");
   }
}
use(111, Ooo);
`;

const regex = /^[^\S\n]*class Ttt {[^]*?\n\s*}\s*\n\s*use\(.*\);$/m;
const m = text.match(regex);

if (m) {
  console.log(m[0]);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if there is a space before the string for example it work `}` it not work ` ....}`.
Where . is a space

Comment: @Alex You can match zero or more spaces before and after the closing curly `^class Ttt {[^]*?\n\s*}\s*\n\s*use\(.*\);$` https://regex101.com/r/LnsbTY/1

Comment: It not work https://regex101.com/r/LnsbTY/2

Comment: @Alex Now it does :-) `^\s*class Ttt {[^]*?\n\s*}\s*\n\s*use\(.*\);$` https://regex101.com/r/7y4xMt/1

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here's a non-regex version:

```
'class ' + text.split('class ')[1]
```

```js
var text = `class Eee {
   test(){
     console.log("123");
   }
}
use(123, Eee);

class Ttt {
   test(){
     console.log("123");
   }
}
use(456, Ttt);


class Ooo {
   test(){
     console.log("123");
   }
}
use(111, Ooo);
`;

console.log('class ' + text.split('class ')[1])
```